# JSF: Hide input when typing in the text box

Tags: jsf

I want to hide the first 6 characters of SSN when user types in the text box. Something like ***-**-1234
Is there any built in tag I can achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The "built in" components of the standard JSF implementation only represents the standard HTML elements. Your functional requirement is not covered by any of those HTML elements, so the standard JSF implementation won't have it as well. The closest one is the HTML `<input type="password">` which is provided by JSF `<h:inputSecret>` component, but this will mask *all* characters instead of only a specified subset.

Also no 3rd party JSF component libraries comes to mind which is able to do this. You have basically 2 options, an easy one and a harder one.

1. Split the SSN over two input fields. One `<h:inputSecret>` and one `<h:inputText>`. Add if necessary some `onkeyup` JavaScript helper code which auto-tabs to the next field when 6 characters are entered. In the server side just glue the two parts together.
2. Use a `<h:inputHidden>` for the value and a normal `<input type="text">` with some `onkeydown` JavaScript helper code which fills the hidden input and returns the masked character to the visible input for the first 6 characters.